# Is there a way to reverse a LinearProgressBar in flutter?

Tags: progress-bar, flutter, reverse

So I want a LinearProgressBar that goes from **right to left**. So basically in reverse.
Is there a line of code I need to add? Couldn't find anything.

```
LinearProgressIndicator (...)
```

Here's what we're already getting:

[image: Left to right progress indicator]

**Here's what we're looking for:**

[image]

Comment: You can achieve the same effect by switching the `valueColor` and `backgroundColor` properties and inverting the progress value.

Comment: Also, you need to do `value: 1 - 0.8` if you want it filled 80%.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Transform widget. I do not have access to test the Matrix4, but it should flip over the y-axis give my map (x, y, z) => (-x, y, z).

```
Transform(
  transform: Matrix4.diagonal3Values(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
  child: LinearProgressIndicator(),
)
```

Comment: hmm... it just disappears now. maybe it is now diplayed offscreen on the left. how can i move the widget by the width of itself?

Comment: It is possible like this: Transform.rotate(
                                angle: pi / 180 * 180,
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: LinearProgressIndicator()),

You will need to import dart math package:
import 'dart:math';